# Python: How to take values from dictionaries and return a True/False evaluation of their mathematical product?

Tags: python, dictionary, boolean

I want to compare 2 dictionaries only if they meet one of two conditions: either they are equivalent or (more likely) they complement each other in a certain way described below. Do evaluate this, I take values from 2 dictionaries, multiply them together, and run them by a True/False statement. This is my function:

```py
def permissible(dict1,dict2):
    a = dict1['conv_factor']
    b = dict2['conv_factor']
    return a*b == 1.0 or dict1 == dict2
```

However, when I execute the function, it comes up False, even when mathematically it comes up as True.

```
source_dict = {'mm': 1, 'cm': 10, 'm': 1000, 'km': 1000000, 'conv_factor': 0.03937007874015748}
```

`dest_dict = {'in': 1, 'ft': 12, 'yd': 36, 'mi': 63360, 'conv_factor': 25.4}`

```
>>>print(permissible(source_dict,dest_dict))
>>>False
```

The multiplication of a x b evaluates to (1/25.4) x 25.4, which equals 1.0. When I have python print a x b, it returns 1.0. So I am not sure why I can't get the boolean statement to return true.

Comment: You have stored an approximate value of `1/25.4` so whrn mulitplyng by 25.4 you don't get 1 exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with floating point arithmetic not being completely precise. If I run the computation in python, I get a value very close but not equal to 1.0.

```py
>>> 0.03937007874015748 * 25.4
0.9999999999999999
```

Instead, check if the value is close enough to 1.

```py
def permissible(dict1,dict2):
    a = dict1['conv_factor']
    b = dict2['conv_factor']
    return abs((a*b) - 1.0) < 0.00001 or dict1 == dict2
```

Comment: Thank you, I was confused about how python was storing the data. The abs() function works well. The only thing is abs() is its own function, not part of the math module in python 3

Answer (score 0):

You have stored an approximate value of `1/25.4`, so multiplying by `25.4` again doesn't give out one

```
print(0.03937007874015748*25.4) # 0.9999999999999999
```

---

But, you're lucky, there is an final value not so far, you may have done `print(1/25.4) # 0.03937007874015748` to get it, to know if there a final value, use a bigher numerator like `10**9`

```
print(10**9/25.4) # 39370078.740157485
```

Which says that the final value you want is `0.039370078740157485 # 5 at the end`

---

For [`comparing float for almost-equality`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) you can do

```
return abs(a*b - 1.0)<0.00001 or dict1 == dict2
```